# CSS margin issue with DIV ids

Tags: html, css

In my below code, I am facing below problems div `expenses_div`. I have added `margin-top:3%;` for it, but somehow its not working.

Also, `expenses_div` is inside `container_input`. but `expenses_div` width is more than the one set for `container_input` (60% of page width). I am not able to understand the issue with `expenses_div`.

Can someone please guide me here

```css
.expenses_wrapper 
{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:50px;
}
  
.expenses_banner
{
 width:100% !important;
 background-color:black;
 position: relative;
 text-align:center;
 color:white;
 padding:5px;
 overflow:hidden !important;
 font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif !important;
 font-size:20px; 
 position:fixed;
 z-index: 105 !important;
}  

.container_input
{
width:100%;
margin-top:5%;
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
}

.expenses_main_head 
{
 width:60%; 
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:80px;
 margin:auto;
}

.expenses_div 
{
width:100% !important;
margin:auto;
margin-top:3%;
}


.expenses_div_left
{
height:40px;
line-height:40px;
background-color:black; 
float:left;
display: inline-block;
text-align:left;
padding-left:12px;
color:white;
width:48%;
font-size: 14px !important;
font-family : "Montserrat",sans-serif !important;
} 


.expenses_div_right
{
height: 40px !important;
line-height: 40px !important;
width:48%;
float:left;
display: inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
background:transparent !important;
position:relative;/*Added (Because :after should be relative to this not whole page! )*/
}


.expenses_div_right select 
{
font-family : "Montserrat",sans-serif !important;
background:transparent !important;
appearance:none !important;
-moz-appearance:none !important;
-webkit-appearance:none !important;
box-sizing: border-box !important;
border: 1px solid black !important;
width:100%!important;
color:black !important;
height:40px;
text-align:left !important;
font-size: 14px !important;
outline: none; 
position: relative !important;
cursor:pointer;
padding-left:12px;
z-index:2;
}

.expenses_div_right:after 
{ 
content: '< >';
font: 16px "Consolas", monospace;
font-weight:bold;
color: white;
background-color:black;
display:inline-block;
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
position: absolute;/*Changed to absolute*/
top:0;/*Added*/
right:0;/*Added*/
width:40px;
height:40px;
text-align:center;
line-height:40px;
overflow:hidden !important;
cursor:pointer;
z-index :1 ;/*Added ( For Your 2nd Question )*/
}


.expenses_input
{
height:40px !important;
line-height: 40px !important;
border: 1px solid black !important;
font-family : "Montserrat",sans-serif !important;
outline: none !important; 
width:100%!important; 
text-align:right;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px !important;
cursor:pointer;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box !important;
-moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="expenses_wrapper" class="expenses_wrapper" >
<div id="expenses_banner" class="expenses_banner" >Tracker</div>  

<div class="container_input" id="container_input"  >
 <div class="expenses_main_head">
  <div class="expenses_div_left" >How to Proceed</div>
  <div id="expenses_div_right" class="expenses_div_right" >
   <select name="expense_main_selection"  id="expense_main_selection" >
    <option selected value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="new_data">New Data</option>
    <option value="analize_data">Analyze Data</option>
    <option value="refresh_data">Refresh Data</option> 
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="expenses_input_date" class="expenses_div" > 
  <div class="expenses_div_left" >Date</div>
  <div class="expenses_div_right" ><input type="text" class="expenses_input" id="expenses_input_date" name="expenses_input_date" autocomplete="off"></div>
 </div> 

 <div id ="expenses_select_account" class="expenses_div" >
  <div class="expenses_div_left" >Select Account</div>
  <div id="expenses_div_right" class="expenses_div_right" >
   <select name="select_account" id="select_account_select">
    <option selected value="">Select Account</option>
    <option value="Opt1">Opt1</option>
    <option value="Opt2">Opt2</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>


</div>
```

Comment: You say, "DIV ids" but there are no IDs in your markup. Did you mean "class" names or "classes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `clear:both` when you use float, Parent div is not taking height when you use float, so use clear:both to clear it.

The clear property is directly related to floats. If the element can fit horizontally in the space next to another element which is floated, it will. Unless you apply clear to that element in the same direction as the float. Then the element will move down below the floated element.

It's probably best practise to keep the names different of `class` and `id` purely for code readability, but there's no issue being same.

```css
.expenses_wrapper 
{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:50px;
}
  
.expenses_banner
{
 width:100% !important;
 background-color:black;
 position: relative;
 text-align:center;
 color:white;
 padding:5px;
 overflow:hidden !important;
 font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif !important;
 font-size:20px; 
 position:fixed;
 z-index: 105 !important;
}  

.container_input
{
width:100%;
margin-top:5%;
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
}

.expenses_main_head 
{
 width:60%; 
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:80px;
 margin:auto;
}

.expenses_div 
{
width:100% !important;
margin:auto;
margin-top:3%;
}


.expenses_div_left
{
height:40px;
line-height:40px;
background-color:black; 
float:left;
display: inline-block;
text-align:left;
padding-left:12px;
color:white;
width:48%;
font-size: 14px !important;
font-family : "Montserrat",sans-serif !important;
} 


.expenses_div_right
{
height: 40px !important;
line-height: 40px !important;
width:48%;
float:left;
display: inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
background:transparent !important;
position:relative;/*Added (Because :after should be relative to this not whole page! )*/
}


.expenses_div_right select 
{
font-family : "Montserrat",sans-serif !important;
background:transparent !important;
appearance:none !important;
-moz-appearance:none !important;
-webkit-appearance:none !important;
box-sizing: border-box !important;
border: 1px solid black !important;
width:100%!important;
color:black !important;
height:40px;
text-align:left !important;
font-size: 14px !important;
outline: none; 
position: relative !important;
cursor:pointer;
padding-left:12px;
z-index:2;
}

.expenses_div_right:after 
{ 
content: '< >';
font: 16px "Consolas", monospace;
font-weight:bold;
color: white;
background-color:black;
display:inline-block;
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
position: absolute;/*Changed to absolute*/
top:0;/*Added*/
right:0;/*Added*/
width:40px;
height:40px;
text-align:center;
line-height:40px;
overflow:hidden !important;
cursor:pointer;
z-index :1 ;/*Added ( For Your 2nd Question )*/
}


.expenses_input
{
height:40px !important;
line-height: 40px !important;
border: 1px solid black !important;
font-family : "Montserrat",sans-serif !important;
outline: none !important; 
width:100%!important; 
text-align:right;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px !important;
cursor:pointer;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box !important;
-moz-appearance: none;
}

.clerafix{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div id="expenses_wrapper" class="expenses_wrapper" >
<div id="expenses_banner" class="expenses_banner" >Tracker</div>  

<div class="container_input" id="container_input"  >
 <div class="expenses_main_head">
  <div class="expenses_div_left" >How to Proceed</div>
  <div id="expenses_div_right" class="expenses_div_right" >
   <select name="expense_main_selection"  id="expense_main_selection" >
    <option selected value="">Select an option</option>
    <option value="new_data">New Data</option>
    <option value="analize_data">Analyze Data</option>
    <option value="refresh_data">Refresh Data</option> 
   </select>
  </div>
    <div class="clerafix"></div>
 </div>

 <div id="expenses_input_date" class="expenses_div" > 
  <div class="expenses_div_left" >Date</div>
  <div class="expenses_div_right" ><input type="text" class="expenses_input" id="expenses_input_date" name="expenses_input_date" autocomplete="off"></div>
    <div class="clerafix"></div>
 </div> 

 <div id ="expenses_select_account" class="expenses_div" >
  <div class="expenses_div_left" >Select Account</div>
  <div id="expenses_div_right" class="expenses_div_right" >
   <select name="select_account" id="select_account_select">
    <option selected value="">Select Account</option>
    <option value="Opt1">Opt1</option>
    <option value="Opt2">Opt2</option>
   </select>
  </div>
    <div class="clerafix"></div>
 </div>

</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any better or effective way to align elements rather than float ?. I need to align expenses_div_left and expenses_div_right in same line

Answer (score 0):

if you can change the width of the `.container_input` to 60% it should work.

```css
.expenses_wrapper {
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:50px;
}
  
.expenses_banner {
 width:100% !important;
 background-color:black;
 position: relative;
 text-align:center;
 color:white;
 padding:5px;
 overflow:hidden !important;
 font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif !important;
 font-size:20px; 
 position:fixed;
 z-index: 105 !important;
}  

.container_input {
  width: 60%;
  margin-top:5%;
  text-align:center;
  margin:auto;
}

.expenses_main_head {
 width:60%; 
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:80px;
 margin:auto;
}

.expenses_div {
  width:100% !important;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:3%;
}


.expenses_div_left {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: black; 
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:left;
  padding-left:12px;
  color:white;
  width:48%;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  font-family : "Montserrat",sans-serif !important;
} 


.expenses_div_right {
  height: 40px !important;
  line-height: 40px !important;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent !important;
  position: relative;/*Added (Because :after should be relative to this not whole page! )*/
}


.expenses_div_right select  {
  font-family : "Montserrat",sans-serif !important;
  background:transparent !important;
  appearance:none !important;
  -moz-appearance:none !important;
  -webkit-appearance:none !important;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  border: 1px solid black !important;
  width:100%!important;
  color:black !important;
  height:40px;
  text-align:left !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  outline: none; 
  position: relative !important;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding-left:12px;
  z-index:2;
}

.expenses_div_right:after { 
  content: '< >';
  font: 16px "Consolas", monospace;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: white;
  background-color:black;
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  position: absolute;/*Changed to absolute*/
  top:0;/*Added*/
  right:0;/*Added*/
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:40px;
  overflow:hidden !important;
  cursor:pointer;
  z-index :1 ;/*Added ( For Your 2nd Question )*/
}


.expenses_input {
  height:40px !important;
  line-height: 40px !important;
  border: 1px solid black !important;
  font-family : "Montserrat",sans-serif !important;
  outline: none !important; 
  width:100%!important; 
  text-align:right;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  cursor:pointer;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="expenses_wrapper" class="expenses_wrapper">
    <div id="expenses_banner" class="expenses_banner">Tracker</div>  
    <div class="container_input" id="container_input">
      <div class="expenses_main_head">
        <div class="expenses_div_left" >How to Proceed</div>
        <div id="expenses_div_right" class="expenses_div_right">
          <select name="expense_main_selection"  id="expense_main_selection" >
            <option selected value="">Select an option</option>
            <option value="new_data">New Data</option>
            <option value="analize_data">Analyze Data</option>
            <option value="refresh_data">Refresh Data</option> 
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="expenses_input_date" class="expenses_div" > 
        <div class="expenses_div_left" >Date</div>
        <div class="expenses_div_right" ><input type="text" class="expenses_input" id="expenses_input_date" name="expenses_input_date" autocomplete="off"></div>
      </div> 
        
      <div id ="expenses_select_account" class="expenses_div" >
        <div class="expenses_div_left" >Select Account</div>
        <div id="expenses_div_right" class="expenses_div_right" >
            <select name="select_account" id="select_account_select">
                <option selected value="">Select Account</option>
                <option value="Opt1">Opt1</option>
                <option value="Opt2">Opt2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```